# OpenGL image disappears on selection if the OS is not Linux

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I need to check if an object or an empty space has been clicked in OpenGL. I capture the click event in the `MouseCallback` function which passes the x and y click coordinates to `ProcessSelection`. The function is:

```
void MouseCallback(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        ProcessSelection(x, y);
}
```

Then I coordinates process the selection coordinates in `ProcessSelection`:

```
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 64
void ProcessSelection(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    printf("xpos: %d\n", xPos);
    printf("ypos: %d\n", yPos);
    GLfloat fAspect;        // Screen aspect ratio
    GLuint selectBuff[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    GLint viewport[4];
    glSelectBuffer(BUFFER_LENGTH, selectBuff);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPickMatrix(xPos, viewport[3] - yPos, 4, 4, viewport);

    fAspect = (float)(viewport[2]) / (float)viewport[3];

    gluPerspective(120, fAspect, 1, 300);
    display();

    // Restore the projection matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);

    if (hits >= 1)
        enable_animation = !enable_animation;
    else
        glutSetWindowTitle("You clicked empty space!");
}
```

The `gluPerspective()` is the exact same function that is called in the reshape function. I noticed that it works well in Linux but not in Windows and Mac OS X where the image disappears at every click. I can't understand why. Can someone help me?

Comment: is the result the same if you remove the hit logic (last 4 lines)?

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: @Andreas Yes, the result is identical

Comment: A problem I've had in the past is that the current OpenGL context stays around once set in Linux, but on Win32 seems to be made current only before a redraw and cleared afterwards. Try setting the current window within ProcessSelection. Or ProcessSelection stores "most recent click here" and calls glutPostRedisplay, the display function checks for a recent click and if so does the selection

Comment: Thanks. If you would post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.